# A topology on $\mathbb{N}$, and sets of accumulation points

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification

The following is a homework question, followed by my solution. I would like to know if my solution is correct.

Question:

Let
$\{\emptyset\}\cup\{\{k \in \mathbb{N} : k \geq n\}: n \in \mathbb{N}\}$
be a topology on $\mathbb{N}$.

1. Find all the accumulation points of the set $A=\{1,3,5,7,11,13\}$.
2. Find all the subsets $B \subseteq \mathbb{N}$ such that the set of their accumulation points is all of $\mathbb{N}$.

Solution:

1. Let us denote
   $A'$ the set of accumulation point of a set $A$.

Thus $A' =\{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12\}$.

2. I propose that all infinite subsets of
   $\mathbb{N}$
   comply with
   $B' = \mathbb{N}$.

Proof: Let
$B \subseteq \mathbb{N}$
be an infinite subset, and let
$x \in \mathbb{N}$
be an arbitrary natural number.
We wish to show that $x$ is an accumulation point of $B$, thus for every neighborhood $M$ of $x$ we can find $b \in B$ such that $x \neq b \in M$.

From the definition of an open set of $x$ under the given topology:

{ $k \in \mathbb{N} : k \geq x$ } $\subseteq M$.

We choose $b \in B$ such that $b>x$. Such one exists because $B$ is infinite.

$b \in M$ because $b>x$, and also meets the requirement of $b \neq x$.

Therefore, given an arbitrary $x \in \mathbb{N}$, and $M$ a neighborhood of $x$, we were able to find $b \in B$ such that $x \neq b \in M$.

$\Rightarrow$ $x$ is an accumulation point of $B$.

Comment: I agree with this

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/tags/solution-verification/info: *"For posts looking for feedback or verification of a proposed solution. "Is my proof correct?" is off topic (too broad, missing context). Instead, the question must identify precisely which step in the proof that is in doubt, and why so [...]"* Whence the 3 votes to close for need of more focus.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your answer is correct as far as it goes, but you haven’t fully answered the question in that you haven’t proved that these sets are all sets that satisfy $B'=\mathbb N$. The proof works in the same spirit as the one you wrote: If $B$ is not infinite, there is a point $x$ larger than all elements of $B$, whose neighbourhood $\{k\in\mathbb N:k\ge x\}$ contains no point of $B$.

Comment: Thank you very much!